# How to include maven built library into your project in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven

I am a novice and don't have much idea. So I have a [library](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/wiki/UserSetup) that is built with Maven and I want to include this library in my java project in Eclipse, how do I do this? I am using Eclipse juno on MacOSx. I want to run one of the [modules](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/wiki/ClearTKTimeML) in this library, so the source code is provided for this module but how do i run this?

Comment: Do your project use maven as well ?

Comment: no I am not using maven.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using maven, you have to download the jar and the sources of that jar (In your case, you can download the zip file provided on the website you mention : http://code.google.com/p/cleartk/downloads/list ) and put it somewhere on your computer.

Then you have to set the build path of your project in Eclipse :

Right-click on your project ->  `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` 
Then you can click on the `Libraries` tab and `Add External Jars` so you can point to the jar you downloaded. 
In this tab, you can attach the sources of this jar to have access to the source code in Eclipse (and eventually set breakpoint).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am trying this now. I will post if I face some problem.

Comment: So I have the jar files in add-external-jars but how do I add the source files corresponding to these jars in my project?

Comment: Once you have the jar in the library tab, open the little `+` on its left, click on `Source Attachment` and then `Edit` and browse to the file or folder containing the sources.

Comment: So I added the source files but when i try to debug the code by opening the .class files under the Referenced Libraries, it gives error source not found.